# enum 'ScriptResults' and enum 'ScriptResults' conflict in class 'ScriptMain' VB script

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, enums

I am having an enum to enum error
I am using Visual Studio 2013 and am trying to write a VB script task.

My code is supposed to copy over a template in excel, (Sheet 2) and rename it with the variable I am going to pass through it in a 4loop
I am getting this compiling error."enum 'ScriptResults' and enum 'ScriptResults' conflict in class 'ScriptMain'"

I know the error resides with my second  Enum ScriptResults and that I should not have two but when I take one of the script results away I get this error all over the place "Reference to class 'ApplicationClass' is not allowed when its assembly is linked using No-PIA mode."

Here is all of my codes, any suggestions?

```
 Imports System
 Imports System.Data
 Imports System.Math
 Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
 Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop


<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
Inherits 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase

Enum ScriptResults
    Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
    Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
End Enum



Public Sub Main()



    Dim Excel As Excel.ApplicationClass = Nothing
    Dim Book As Excel.WorkbookClass = Nothing
    Dim Books As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
    Dim sFilePath As String = CStr(Dts.Variables("User::CopyClaimsSubmission").Value)
    Dim excelWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Try


        'Start Excel and open the workbook.
        Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Excel.Visible = False
        Books = Excel.Workbooks
        Book = Books.Open(sFilePath)

        If Book.Sheets.Count > 0 Then
            'copy first worksheet
            Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy(Type.Missing, Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2))
            'select the copy
            excelWorkSheet = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)

            'test: show the new name
            'MsgBox(excelWorkSheet.Name.ToString +" rename to " CStr(Dts.Variables("User::Iterator_Item").Value))

            'rename the sheet
            excelWorkSheet.Name = CStr(Dts.Variables("User::Membersneedingclaimsdata").Value)
        End If

        'Clean-up: Close the workbook and quit Excel.
        Book.Save()
        Excel.Quit()

        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success


    Finally
        If Book IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Book)
        If Books IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Books)
        If Excel IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Excel)


        Book = Nothing
        Books = Nothing
        Excel = Nothing

    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question what I did was pull out the initial enumeration script results and then replaced everything so they are not longer a class so the class error would go away. IT WORKS!

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop



<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
Inherits 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase




Public Sub Main()



    Dim Excel As Excel.Application = Nothing
    Dim Book As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim Books As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
    Dim sFilePath As String = CStr(Dts.Variables("User::CopyClaimsSubmission").Value)
    Dim excelWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Try


        'Start Excel and open the workbook.
        Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Excel.Visible = False
        Books = Excel.Workbooks
        Book = Books.Open(sFilePath)

        If Book.Sheets.Count > 0 Then
            'copy first worksheet
            Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Copy(Type.Missing, Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2))
            'select the copy
            excelWorkSheet = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3)

            'test: show the new name
            'MsgBox(excelWorkSheet.Name.ToString +" rename to " CStr(Dts.Variables("User::Iterator_Item").Value))

            'rename the sheet
            excelWorkSheet.Name = CStr(Dts.Variables("User::forloopenumorator").Value)
        End If

        'Clean-up: Close the workbook and quit Excel.
        Book.Save()
        Excel.Quit()

        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success


    Finally
        If Book IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Book)
        If Books IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Books)
        If Excel IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Excel)


        Book = Nothing
        Books = Nothing
        Excel = Nothing

    End Try

End Sub

Enum ScriptResults
    Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
    Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
End Enum
```

End Class